# Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker linked pickers adds 1 minute

Tags: datetimepicker

Bootstrap 3 Datepicker sometimes adds one minute when using linked pickers. When using the option stepping: 0, you still get one minute extra.

[image]

You can try it on this website under 'Linked pickers': http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
  $('.datum-tijd-van').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'nl',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
  });
  $('.datum-tijd-tot').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'nl',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
  });
  $(".datum-tijd-van").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('.datum-tijd-tot').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
  });
  $(".datum-tijd-tot").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    // $('.datum-tijd-van').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date); // disabled this one
  });
});
```